# Is it faster to compare or reassign a bool in a loop?

Tags: oop, optimization, variable-assignment

The question is:  is it faster to do that:

```
if (!self.isStarted)
{
     self.started = YES;
}
```

or simply:

```
self.started = YES;
```

and reassign the value at each passing loop.

Comment: 1) It depends 2) It doesn't matter

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking the two different approaches?  And which language are you using? :)

Comment: Wild guess: It doesn't matter. The branch predictor will probably practically skip the if, and the assignment will be on par with that.

Also, holy mirco-optimization batman!

Comment: It probably depends on the language

Comment: it's objective-c btw. I was wondering because if feel its stupid testing but maybe it even more stupid reassigning

Comment: It also depends on the variable. If it is volatile it could make a non negligible difference.

Comment: **Please don't worry about "fastest" without having first done some sort of measurement that it matters.**
Rather than worrying about fastest, think about which way is clearest.

Comment: well fast meant clean for me. It's amazing how people really know what the question is and still try to find ways to fart always higher..something along (just assign it's fine was enough no need to boast your lonelyness on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional is slower, and isn't as clear as simply setting the variable to YES.  The point of your code is that you want to ensure the variable is YES after you leave that bit of code, and since the operation is so inexpensive in the grand scheme of things, go for readability, and just set it to YES without checking beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

While a compiler would likely optimize this anyway, `self.started = YES;` will be faster, because it saves the overhead of having to retreive the value from memory and compare it. This answer is only valid for low-level languages; higher-level languages will be implementation dependent.

Comment: this was in objective-c. I wondered if readying memory is faster than writing